# Question Pre-Screen

Tags: discussion

**Is this question ok to ask on the EE.SE?**

### Question

How high is the voltage stepped up in a typical fluorescent light bulb?  CFL take in 120 VAC and steps it up using a mini transformer in a CFL.  About how high is the output of that transformer?

Answer (score 2):

I would vote to close because the question makes no sense.

Comment: How about now is it good?

Comment: @Sigma6RPU Better, but still unanswerable without specific knowledge of the CFL's design.

Answer (score 2):

The general concept is valid, but your specific question is not so good.

In particular, you should avoid lecturing in a question.  This makes questions hard to answer because the sometimes incorrect statements would have to be dispelled before a real answer can be given.  In particular, loose *"CFL take in 120 VAC and steps it up using a mini transformer in a CFL."*.

Step back and think about what you really want to know.  In this case it seems you want to know what voltage is used internally in a compact fluorescent lamp.  If that is really your question, don't confuse things by trying to tell us how such lamps work.

The real question would be too broad if asking about all CFLs.  It might be acceptable to ask about a particular model, or to ask how to go about finding the voltage used in such a lamp.